# How to join two tables and create a new table to check in which table value exists using sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two tables and create a new table to check in which table value exists using sql

Table A

```
Student ID   Name
1            abcd
2            efgh
3            ijkl
4            mnop
5            erst
6            uvwx
```

Table B

```
Student ID   Name
1            qwer
2            west
3            ijkl
4            mnop
7            ikjh
8            iolk
```

Output To Be

```
Student ID   Name    New Column
1            abcd    Present in A
2            efgh    Present in A
3            ijkl    Both
4            mnop    Both
5            erst    Present in A
6            uvwx    Present in A
7            ikjh    Present in B
8            iolk    Present in B
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved using SQL.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Don't spam tags. Just tag the DBMS you're really using.

Comment: Why are 'qwer' and  'west' from TableB missing from your results?

Comment: You need a full outer join what I see here? Please tag your DBMS as said before to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Yes, it would be FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `FULL JOIN`:

```
select id, name,
       (case when a.id is not null and b.id is not null then 'Both'
             when a.id is not null then 'A Only'
             else 'B Only'
        end) as new_column
from a full join
     b
     using (id, name)
```